# Slow response when use shell_exec

Tags: php, powershell

i have issue when execute PowerShell command using php function `shell_exec()` thru .ps1 file. below script has taken around 8 second to retrieve data

```
$myfile = fopen("C:\\TestNew\\GetUserInfo.ps1", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

$output= shell_exec('C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -file "C:\\TestNew\\GetUserInfo.ps1"  2>&1 ');
```

How to minimize execution time?

Comment: What have you done to diagnose the issue? Try using [`procmon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) or other process tracing utilities to observe what's actually taking up the time - does the `powershell.exe` process start immediately, or is it delayed? Do you see significant delays between powershell reading the script file from disk until anything actually happens?

Comment: To add to Mathias' comment: One thing generally worth doing is to suppress invocation of PowerShell's profile files in non-interactive, execute-and-exit calls to the PowerShell CLI: place `-noprofile` before `-file`. However, unless the code that causes the delay happens to be in your profile(s), this won't solve your problem.